# Meteor dependencies on document vs collection

Tags: meteor

Is there a way to make a Meteor dependency on a particular subscription depend only on the documents in the collection and not the data in the documents?

For example, say I have a collection of users. I publish:

```
Meteor.publish("Users_All", function () {
    return Users.find();
});
```

On the client I have a particular dependency which is established after subscribing to the collection:

```
Deps.autorun(function () {
    // run some expensive computation on Users.find().fetch();
});
```

I only want to run my computation when a new document is added or a document is removed from the collection. However, right now it's called whenever a particular element in any document is set too. How would I structure a dependency such that this is not the case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could manually add and remove documents from your published set, ignoring document changes.

```
Meteor.publish("Users_All", function () {

  var self = this;

  var handle = Users.find().observeChanges({
    added: function (id, fields) {
      self.added('users', id, fields);
    },
    removed: function (id) {
      self.removed('users', id);
    }
  });

  self.ready();

  self.onStop(function () {
    handle.stop();
  });
});
```

**Note:** The first arg to `added` and `removed` should be the name of the collection. I just assumed `'users'`.

Meteor's [publish](http://docs.meteor.com/#meteor_publish) docs have more information and examples.